# Javascript If & else to reveal & hide <div>'s

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I feel my question falls under this topic, although maybe a little more complicated:

I have one single wrapper  which will be constantly visible and have a css background.

However the elements within this div make up a final visual image based on a products values.

**So for example:**

Upper section needs to have the if & else to hide / reveal contents based on database value, so if the database row under 'header_4' for example contains 'B' then it will show only `<div id="B_LT"><p>B</p></div><!-- end of 'B_LT' -->`

But at the same time if the value within the row under 'header_5' contains 'D' will also show `<div id="D_RT"><p>D</p></div><!-- end of 'D_RT' -->` at the same time as the above `<div>`.

I do not need to hide the two lower sections but in addition to this need to always show the datab

```
<!-- ########### UPPER SECTION STARTS ########## -->

<div id="wrp">

<div id="left_top">

<div id="A_LT">
<p>A</p>
</div><!-- end of 'A_LT' -->

<div id="B_LT">
<p>B</p>
</div><!-- end of 'B_LT' -->

<div id="C_LT">
<p>C</p>
</div><!-- end of 'C_LT' -->

<div id="D_LT">
<p>D</p>
</div><!-- end of 'D_LT' -->

<div id="E_LT">
<p>E</p>
</div><!-- end of 'E_LT' -->

<div id="F_LT">
<p>F</p>
</div><!-- end of 'F_LT' -->

<div id="G_LT">
<p>G</p>
</div><!-- end of 'G_LT' -->

</div><!-- end of 'left_top' -->


<div id="right_top">

<div id="A_RT">
<p>A</p>
</div><!-- end of 'A_RT' -->

<div id="B_RT">
<p>B</p>
</div><!-- end of 'B_RT' -->

<div id="C_RT">
<p>C</p>
</div><!-- end of 'C_RT' -->

<div id="D_RT">
<p>D</p>
</div><!-- end of 'D_RT' -->

<div id="E_RT">
<p>E</p>
</div><!-- end of 'E_RT' -->

<div id="F_RT">
<p>F</p>
</div><!-- end of 'F_RT' -->

<div id="G_RT">
<p>G</p>
</div><!-- end of 'G_RT' -->

</div><!-- end of 'right_top' -->


<!-- ########### LOWER SECTION STARTS ########## -->

<div id="left_bottom">

<!-- 
Database returns value and Reveals relevant <div> based on returned value
Example: if database returns the numerical value '2' then the associated <div> for 2 bars is revealed.
<div id="BAR2_LB"><img src="bar2.png" /></div><!-- end of 'BAR2_LB' -->
-->

<div id="BAR0_LB">
<img src="bar0.png" />
</div><!-- end of 'BAR0_LB' -->

<div id="BAR1_LB">
<img src="bar1.png" />
</div><!-- end of 'BAR1_LB' -->

<div id="BAR2_LB">
<img src="bar2.png" />
</div><!-- end of 'BAR2_LB' -->

<div id="BAR3_LB">
<img src="bar3.png" />
</div><!-- end of 'BAR3_LB' -->

</div><!-- end of 'left_bottom' -->


<div id="right_bottom">

<div id="DB_RB">
<p>40</p><!-- Database returned value -->
</div><!-- end of 'DB_RB' -->

</div><!-- end of 'right_bottom' -->

</div><!-- end of 'wrp' -->

<!-- ########### HIDE / REVEAL ENDS ########## -->
```

If anyone is able to assist with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

///////////////////// EDIT //////////////////////////////////////

Thanks for the responses, to try help clarify a little more.

The site this will be used for is written in ASP.Net 2.0 (Being re-developed in the new year, but need this in place asap as a requirement by the boss.)

I am thinking to use JavaScript for the hide reveal function but I think I have a bigger issue that has come to light since posting the above.

This issue being that I am unable to find (the chap before me's) original copy of the site files with the 'code behind' files included.

I only have the pre-compiled site at this stage.

But I am thinking to use JavaScript for the hide & reveal of the  sections but to then simply pull the data from the database tables using ASP but I am new to ASP and getting a lost especially as it appears that the original site has been deleted by my past colleague in spite possibly.

Man I need help with this one.......

Thanks to all so far.

Comment: what is the problem? what do you need help in?

Comment: After an ajax call, or on initial page rendering?

Comment: Don't drag the logic to DOM , do it within the db query e.g using sorting order and specific classes like "active" ,"in_active". I think you need to put some more detail here

Comment: how (what language / framework) do you read / write from your database and construct your page?  Because when server side, just write out <div id="BAR"+<database value>+"_LB">
<img src="bar"+<database value>+".png" />
</div>